# Divide square image to N number of equal rectangles in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, image, algorithm, web

I have a web page with a square image and I want to divide this image into **n** number equal sized parts, where **n** is defined by the user when he clicks on a button with a number.

For exmaple:

`Button with number 5  ----> Divides the square image to 5 equal parts`

`Button with number 4  ----> Divides the square image to 4 equal parts`

etc..

And I want those parts to be clickable and lead me to another page.
I don't even know what should I use.

Any suggestions, open for anything? Some algorithm or something I don't know ... hope you can help me!

Cheers! :)

Comment: What does "5 equal parts" mean exactly? Like, if you had a square piece of paper, and I asked you to cut it up with scissors into 5 equal parts, what would you do?

Comment: @Pointy I'll try to cut it into some kind of rectangles, but triangles will do the work too I think..

Comment: Please check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571131/how-to-divide-image-into-three-equal-parts-in-php-imagemagick-and-combine-with-s

Comment: `I don't even know what should I use` - javascript

Comment: How to determine wich rectangles you want? For example, if you take 12 equal cells, you can cut the square in `3*4` or `2*6` or `1*12` parts. Wich one should the algo choose, and why?

Comment: @Thomas I thought a little bit and I realized that not every time will be possible to divide the square into equal cells. And I think that it will be okay if only the square is divided by any kind of N number rectangles

Comment: yes, it can: worst case scenario: n equal strips. But the problem is still, that pretty much nothing is defined. And `but triangles will do the work too` made it even worse. You now have **a square and** want to divide it into **a varying amount of** (now **undefined) shapes** and want **to link** these areas **to** (also **undefined) urls**, by an **undefined mapping**. Just read the bold parts and you get the description of this question. You have to start and fill some of these gaps.

Comment: @Thomas I found a solution which suits me perfectly - you can see my answer to the question.
Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some kind of a solution of the problem with making a 4x4 square and divide it to equal 1x1 squares. And then make selectable only N number of tiles.

I hope this helps someone.

`Here is demo`:

http://jsfiddle.net/ivanivanov/HmpGx/149/